# Parallel Streams concept

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I am exploring Java streams and wanted to know if there is anything wrong with this code. Since I am using parallel stream, I have used ConcurrentHashMap.

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

and

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Person> map = <Mapping of id to Person>
List<Integer> list = <list of Id>

list = list.parallelStream()
        .filter(id -> map.containsKey(id)
                      && !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(map.get(id).getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: "if there is anything wrong with this code" do you get any error/wrong results?

Comment: I am just wondering if accessing the map in this context will cause any undesirable results.

Comment: It may depends on what you mean by *undesirable*. Also what do you mean by accessing? Can other thread modify this map when it is streamed? Can this modification be ignored by stream?

Comment: I edited the question...I am worried that since I am using parallel stream, I have to account for synchronizing, locking etc..To support full concurrency of retrievals, I have used concurrentHashMap. My question is "Am I missing something else which I should account for ?"

Comment: @user3704576, no, you should not care about concurrency/locking here. Usual `HashMap` will work as well and would be even faster. Btw, how many elements are usually in your `list`? Have you tested whether parallel version is actually faster? Probably it's not.

Comment: @TagirValeev I haven't tested if parallel is faster...but the list size will be around 50k

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the map is being actively updated, you may have a race between `containsKey` and `get`.  Instead, you might write something like

```
list.parallelStream()
    .filter(id -> {
       Person person = map.get(id);
       return person != null && !Strings.isNullOrEmpty(person.getName());
     })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using `parallelStream` has nothing to do with this -- that's fine.  It's doing two separate calls to the `ConcurrentMap` on the same key and expecting them to have consistent results that's the problem.

Comment: Yeah, the *check-then-act* antipattern. You may also use either `.filter(id -> Optional.ofNullable(map.get(id)).map(Person::getName).filter(s->!s.isEmpty()).isPresent())` or the slightly shorter `.filter(id -> !Optional.ofNullable(map.get(id)).map(Person::getName).orElse("").isEmpty())` though I prefer the first variant for clarity… In either case, 3rd party library methods like `Strings.isNullOrEmpty` are obsolete.

Answer (score 2):

The map is concurrent, so it can handle multi-threaded access. No synchronizing or locking needed.

In your case, a regular `HashMap` would work too, because you are only querying the map. As long a nobody *updates* the list while streaming, you have no multi-threaded contention.